# Ошибка, не может найти метод а он есть, vue ('getIntervall' is not defined). Подскажите кто знает почему ошибка?

Tags: vue.js

```
methods: {
add() {
  const currentTicker = {
    name: this.ticker,
    price: '-',
  };
  this.tickers.push(currentTicker);

  let timerId = setInterval(async () => {
    const f = await fetch(
      `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${currentTicker.name}&tsyms=USD&api_key=f93980b4b77ce870b9c39d9776ecf080db26ae45a430b3417450aca38e66d4b1`
    ); //  https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist?summary=true
    const data = await f.json();
    console.log(data);

    this.tickers.find((t) => t.name === currentTicker.name).price = data.USD > 1 ? data.USD.toFixed(2) : data.USD.toPrecision(2); // toPrecision(2) вывод только два знака после 0

    if (this.select?.name === currentTicker.name) {
      this.graph.push(data.USD);
    }
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }, 18000);

  this.ticker = '';
},

add2 () {
    let timerId2 = getIntervall (async () => {
    const f2 = await fetch( `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist?summary=true`
    );
    //  https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist?summary=true
    const data2 = await f2.json();
    console.log(data2);
  }, 3000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(timerId2);
  }, 10000);
},

selection(ticker) {
  // чтоб график очищался
  this.select = ticker;
  this.graph = [];
},

handleDelete(tickerToRemove, ind) {
  //this.tickers = this.tickers.filter((t) => t !== tickerToRemove);

  this.tickers.splice(ind, 1);
  // написать удаление через splice
},
normalizeGraph() {
  const maxValue = Math.max(...this.graph);
  const minValue = Math.min(...this.graph);
  return this.graph.map((price) => 5 + ((price - minValue) * 95) / (maxValue - minValue));
},
```

},

Comment: "а он есть" - где?

Comment: add2 () {
    let timerId2 = getIntervall

Comment: да точно служебное слово же

Comment: Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//let timerId2 = getIntervall (async () => {
let timerId2 = setInterval (async () => {
```